# Merge rows separated by comma in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing as below:

| id | cat | code | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 197 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 197 | 2 |
| 2 | C.1 | 233 | 1 |
| 2 | C.2 | 240 | 1 |

Is there a way I can concatenate the records separated by comma as following

| id | cat | code | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B | 197 | 1,2 |

I tried using GROUP_CONCAT() but for some reason, it doesn't retrieve all the records

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CAT),GROUP_CONCAT(Class),code FROM T1 GROUP BY code
```

Comment: Firstly, you really should not use images (I cannot see them due to network policy) always use text tables in preference. Secondly, group_concat() generally works as expected - what you need to do is explain why it isn't working for you. Provide the query you used and show the result (so we can see why it didn't get all the records). In short you need more info in the question, so that we can give you an answer. Again, I urge yo to avoid images.

Comment: I've tried using text table but the format changes on submitting the body. the query I used is - SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CAT),GROUP_CONCAT(CODE),CLASS FROM T1 GROUP BY CLASS

Comment: The editor has an icon of curly braces {}  - highight the text that you need in fixed format and click that button. See the question now

Comment: Show an example of what it returns and rows that weren't retrieved?

Comment: Why do you want id when grouping by code?  Which id are you expecting?

Comment: You possibly get the same errors as here - https://dbfiddle.uk/NdoIg2M6 , if so you should publish the error in full

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id,    -- if you need another criteria for `id` selection
                         -- then edit accordingly
       GROUP_CONCAT(cat ORDER BY cat) AS cats, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(class ORDER BY cat) AS classes,
       code 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the verified query for excepted output

SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(CAT,', '),STRING_AGG(Class, ', '),code FROM T1 GROUP BY code

Comment: 'Here is the verified query for excepted output'- mysql does not have string_agg And if you do have verified example it would be helpful if you published to a fiddle. eg dbfiddle.uk